# Heroku Express /w NextJS PORT

Tags: express, heroku, next.js

I've got an express app with a nextJS frontend both deploy together on Heroku. Due to Heroku's dynamic port assignment, I'm trying to pass the PORT into the static nextJS build so that it knows how to call the API i.e

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT;    
fetch(`https://localhost:${PORT}/api/blah`)
```

I've tried the following in my package.json but it doesn't seem to work:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "nodemon",
    "build": "next build && tsc --project tsconfig.server.json",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js -p $PORT"
  },
```

The port is accessible within the NODE application but not within the client repo.

Comment: "Due to Heroku's dynamic port assignment, I'm trying to pass the PORT into the static nextJS build so that it knows how to call the API"—this is wrong. Heroku's dynamic port is just what the backend should bind to; incoming requests still come from standard ports 80 (for HTTP) or 443 (for HTTPS). If clients needed to know the dynamic port, how would anybody ever access your site?

Comment: (Also, server-side environment variables aren't accessible client-side. Even if you needed `PORT` you can't do it at runtime. You'd have to compile it into the client at build time. But, again, you don't need to do this.)

Comment: Also, don't use `localhost`. Use whatever your Heroku domain is.

Comment: 1. Heroku Apps run from local host 2. App environmental vars can be added add built time (which is done on Heroku - at which time the port is known) - you can actually even do it runtime 3. I’m not talking external URL

Comment: You do have stand alone front end Heroku apps - which don’t have a backend

Comment: I'm trying to help but it sounds like you just want to argue. 1. "Heroku Apps run from local host"— _everything_ runs on _some_ `localhost`. But not all `localhost`s are equal. You can't necessarily _access things_ via `localhost`. Your client runs in your user's browser, and connections are made _from there_. If your user's browser tries to connect to `localhost` it will be their laptop, for example, not Heroku.

Comment: 2. I'm not sure what you mean, but client-side code definitely _cannot_ access server-side environment variables. They're literally not running in that environment. They can be compiled in or, I suppose, injected on the fly as responses are sent from the server. 3. What does "I'm not talking external URL" mean? 4. What do front-end-only Heroku apps have to do with anything?

Answer (score 0):

Except for your `package.json` , you don't need to use `${PORT}` in all other frontend files.

Use `fetch('/api/user/2024')`   instead of `fetch ('http://localhost:3000/api/user/2024')` .

If you stumble upon any `absolute URL error` during heroku build(can be seen during build process i.e build log). Use `fetch('http://appname.herokuapp.com/api/user/2024')` instead of `fetch('/api/user/2024')` and replace `appname` with your `heroku appname` .